# Gatling : How to split value getting from the Feeder?

Tags: java, scala, gatling

In a csv file I've something like this

```
term
testing
```

I want to split testing into characters. I want something like this :

```
.feed(Feeders.search)
    .foreach("${term}".toList, "search") {
      exec(http("Auto Complete")
      .get("${baseUrlHttps}/search/autocomplete")
      .queryParam("term", "${search}")
      .check(status is 200)
      .check(jsonPath("$..products[0].code").optional.saveAs("code"))).pause(MIN_PAUSE, MAX_PAUSE)
     }
```

The above code is not working as I wanted, it's splitting "${term}" into characters though I wanted to convert word "testing" which is in csv in to characters. Is there any workaround for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how autocomplete works. You're not posting chars by chars, you're reposting with one more char. Eg, you'll be posting "test", then "testi" then "testin" and finally "testing" (there's usually a minimum length.

```scala
exec { session =>
  val term = session("term").as[String]
  val parts = for (i <- 3 to term.size) yield term.substring(0, i)
  session.set("parts", parts)
}
.foreach("${parts}", "search") {
  exec(http("Auto Complete")
    .get("${baseUrlHttps}/search/autocomplete")
    .queryParam("term", "${search}")
    .check(status is 200)
    .check(jsonPath("$..products[0].code").optional.saveAs("code"))).pause(MIN_PAUSE, MAX_PAUSE)
}
```